# "County" appended to end of county name?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api, google-geolocation

Relevant google geocoding documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types

Google's own Geocoding developer documentation shows examples that return information that includes the following:

> ```
>     <address_component>
>         <long_name>Santa Clara</long_name>
>         <short_name>Santa Clara</short_name>
>         <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
>         <type>political</type>
>     </address_component>
> ```

However, when I use their URL that corresponds to that example it returns XML that includes:

> ```
> <address_component>
>    <long_name>Santa Clara County</long_name>
>    <short_name>Santa Clara County</short_name>
>    <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
>    <type>political</type> 
> </address_component>
> ```

Notice that " County" added to the end of the county name.

Does anyone know if this is intentional? We do not recall seeing the additional " County" last week.

Is this a documented change?

Comment: The data in the geocoding database changes frequently, looks like this changed in the last update.  Don't know of any change log for the geocoder data.

Comment: For customers paying for the geocoding service that seems bad to just change stuff like that. Worse...they change it but do not change their own documentation

Comment: If you are a paying customer (I am not), you should be able to raise it with your contacts at Google.  Where is it documented?  Or are you referring to an example in the documentation?

Comment: Someone in my organization is contacting Google about the change. The only documentation I have been made aware of is the URL in my original post.

Comment: I would consider that an "example" off what the response _could_ look like and the actual data in the response could change over time.

Comment: I could go along with your "example" theory if it weren't for the fact that for 2+ years before Feb 2014 google geocoding did not return county values with the ending " County"

Comment: The data changed.  Nothing says it won't.  In fact they expect it to periodically change (more the actual coordinates, but...)